# SQL Server: use the record in Join/Cross Apply only once

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want my Cross Apply to remove a record if it's joined and not consider it for join in other records. Is it possible to do this in one statement?

So in the example below, The desired result is to have MatchID = 1 for the second record because B.recordID = 2 is already taken by the first record. I believe the sample code will make it clear:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/555a1/5/0

So in summary I need the records in table B not to be considered available anymore if they're used as match.

EDIT1 : Adding the sample code:

Build the Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE A 
(
    id int,
    eventName varchar(80),
    startdateTime datetime,
    duration int,
    MatchedID int NULL
)

CREATE TABLE B 
(
    id int,
    eventName varchar(80),
    startdateTime datetime,
    duration int
)

INSERT INTO A
    SELECT 1, 'e1', dateadd(day, -1, getdate()), 5, NULL
    UNION 
    SELECT 2, 'e1', dateadd(hour, -1, getdate()), 5, NULL

INSERT INTO B
    SELECT 1, 'e1', dateadd(day, -1, getdate()), 4
    UNION 
    SELECT 2, 'e1', dateadd(hour, -1, getdate()), 5
```

Query:

```
UPDATE toUpdate
SET toUpdate.MatchedID = Tbtmp.id
FROM A toUpdate
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP(1) *
             FROM B WHERE toUpdate.eventName = B.eventName
             ORDER BY ABS(toUpdate.Duration - B.Duration)) Tbtmp;

SELECT * FROM A
```

Result:

```
| id | eventName |            startdateTime | duration | MatchedID |
+----+-----------+--------------------------+----------+-----------+
|  1 |        e1 | 2017-10-11T11:34:15.083Z |        5 |         2 |
|  2 |        e1 | 2017-10-12T10:34:15.083Z |        5 |         2 |
```

expected Result (MatchedID for second record should be 1 because 2 is used already even though is closer to the original record)

```
| id | eventName |            startdateTime | duration | MatchedID |
+----+-----------+--------------------------+----------+-----------+
|  1 |        e1 | 2017-10-11T11:34:15.083Z |        5 |         2 |
|  2 |        e1 | 2017-10-12T10:34:15.083Z |        5 |         1 |
```

Comment: You should put code and sample data in your question.  The question should not rely on an external site to be understood.

Comment: Expected result? and detailed explanation for the same as well.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai expected result is added. Thx

Comment: @GordonLinoff Added the code and sample data. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try this? For remove duplicate records ( because of eventName join) I use additional CTE. I tested it with your sample data and it seems working. I hope it works with your real data as well.

```
;WITH toUpdate AS
(
    SELECT *, 
        RN_Update = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY A.eventName ORDER BY A.id) 
    FROM A
)
, fromSource AS
(
    SELECT B.*,
        A.RN_Update, 
        RN_Source = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY A.eventName, A.id ORDER BY A.id, ABS(A.Duration - B.Duration)) 
    FROM B
        INNER JOIN toUpdate A ON A.eventName = B.eventName 
)
UPDATE toUpdate 
SET
    MatchedID = fromSource.id
FROM toUpdate
    INNER JOIN fromSource ON toUpdate.eventName = fromSource.eventName
                AND toUpdate.RN_Update = fromSource.RN_Source
                AND fromSource.RN_Update = fromSource.RN_Source
```

Result:

```
id          eventName   startdateTime           duration    MatchedID
----------- ----------- ----------------------- ----------- -----------
1           e1          2017-10-11 15:33:11.890 5           2
2           e1          2017-10-12 14:33:11.890 5           1
```

Comment: Unfortunately the solution didn't work with my real data however it's not your fault and as you said it works on the sample data so I'm gonna accept this as answer. thanks